# nothing happens when I run plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I wrote a plugin that included another plugin, but nothing happens when I run it. Please check this out and help me.

This is the first plugin, and  this is the main plugin

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: DB Testsed
Description: a simple plugin
Version: 1.0
Author: Ak
Text Domain: HOooooooo
// */
 include "ADT_db.php";
?>
```

This is the second plugin, which I added in the main plugin

```
<?php
function scratchcode_create_payment_table()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "ADT";
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
      id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      user_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      created_at datetime NOT NULL,
      expires_at datetime NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY id (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
    addMenu();
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'scratchcode_create_payment_table');
```

Comment: `include "ADT_db.php";` Is this how you activate the second plugin? Is the second plugin file in the same folder as the first one? What happens if you `require` instead of `include`?

Comment: Also, in order to trigger `register_activation_hook` have you activated the second plugin from wordpress admin?

Comment: Yes they are in a folder.

Comment: no I do not think so.
How can I activate?

Comment: When I put the code in the main plugin, a comment mode is created in the tbl database but not in the other plugin at all.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that activating plugins programmatically is very bad practice and very unsafe. That said, you shouldn't need to include or require admin core functions in your plugin since they are already included on bootstrap. See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/how-to-activate-plugins-via-code)